# return data from executeAsync to the calling function (javascript/mozilla)

Tags: javascript, firefox, parameters, storage, mozilla

I'm new to Javascript and trying to write a firefox add-on.
I am trying to pass/ extract the data returned from a SQL query to the calling function.
It doesn't seem to work.
I searched info on variable scope, looked at any relevant post I coulld see on this site,  and tried examples that were said to work, but none works for me.

I am using the storage info from:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Storage
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/mozIStorageStatement

What do I do wrong, or how should I do this?
I am running firefox 12 on xp.

```
function Sqlite() {
   this.dbConn = "";
   this.empty = true;
}

Sqlite.prototype.retrieveData = function(query)
{
    var rows = new Array(); // to be returned to the calling function
    var stmt = this.dbConn.createStatement(query); // my "select..." statement

    stmt.executeAsync ({
     handleResult: function(aResultSet)
     {
        this.empty = false;
        var i = 0;
        for (let row; row = aResultSet.getNextRow();i++) {
           rows[i] = row;
        }
     },

     handleError: function(anError) {
        //some code
     },

     handleCompletion: function(aReason) {
        if (this.empty) {
            // CODE FOR WHEN STATEMENT EXECUTION IS FINISHED
        }
        if (aReason == Ci.mozIStorageStatementCallback.REASON_FINISHED) {
           document.getElementById("debug").value = rows[0]; //gets the data from the query: [xpconnect wrapped mozIStorageRow]
           return true;
         }
     }
    });  
    document.getElementById("debug").value = rows[0]; //gets undefined
    stmt.finalize();

    return rows;  // the info is no longer available at this point.
}
```

I'll really appreciate your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're somehow vague in the way you're describing your problem, but when you write:

`return rows;  // the info is no longer available at this point.`

this is of course *expected*. `executeAsync`, as the name implies, is asynchronous. That means that when you call `executeAsync`, the action is scheduled *for later*. Javascript has a run-to-completion semantics, so the execution will continue until the `return rows` statement is reached. At this point, the query has not been executed yet! Once your function is finished, the JS engine will execute your asynchronous statement and your `handleCompletion` callback will be called. It is then up to the code in `handleCompletion` to do whatever you want with the data, e.g. call another function to do something with it.

Also, your `empty` variable seems unneeded.

```
handleCompletion: function(aReason) {
   if (aReason != Ci.mozIStorageStatementCallback.REASON_FINISHED) {
     // something went wrong
   } else {
     // do something useful with rows
   }
},
```

Finally, you need to call `row.getResultByName` to get the value of a column in the row.

Comment: Sorry about the vague, I thought I was clear. But you understood, because you led me to a solution.
Thank you for it.
(I extracted the columns but it wasn't relevant for the problem)
Here's what I did:

<pre><code>
  handleCompletion: function(aReason) {
  if (aReason == Ci.mozIStorageStatementCallback.REASON_FINISHED) {
   if (!this.empty) {
    return copyRes(rows, myRows, descResults);
   }
  }
  else {
  Cu.reportError("Async statement execution completed (" + aError.result +
     "): " + aError.message);
  }
  }
</code></pre>
However, is this an elegant way to do it?

Comment: I'd vote you up, but I am too new. Not enough rep.
Thank you again

Comment: I think you're confusing a request that successfully returned zero rows (because the table is empty) with a request that failed (because the db is corrupted, for instance). Otherwise, yes, that sounds fine.

Comment: Also, please edit your post to use proper formatting. Thanks! :)

Comment: errr... Format: I tried. It doesn't work.   
Also, now, I don't have "edit" option at all on the previous comment. Only delete.  
How do I edit the code to look properly? using "code" doesn't do the format.   


About the handleCompletion: Why confused?   
The call to reportError is only in case the aReason is not REASON_FINISHED.   
There's no "else" on the empty situation. Please explain?   
(or is it the bad formatting?)

Comment: Sorry, the lack of formatting confused me. It looks all good!

Comment: I take it when @JonathanProtzenko says `// do something useful with rows` that something useful can't include "have it be the return value of `Sqlite.prototype.retrieveData`"?  Does getting query result as method return value require using a synchronous statement?